# $A\in F_\tau\land\tau(\omega)<\infty\Rightarrow A\in F_{\tau(\omega)}$

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times, filtrations

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space and $(F_t)_{t\in I}$ a filtration. We postulate that $F_t$ is the information available at time $t$. Furthermore, if $\tau$ is a stopping time, then $F_\tau$ ([the $\sigma$-algebra of the $\tau$-past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-Algebra_of_%CF%84-past)) is interpreted as the information available at time $\tau$. That being said, I would expect that given some $A\in F_\tau$ and $\omega\in\Omega$ with $\tau(\omega)<\infty$, then $A\in F_{\tau(\omega)}$. Is this correct? I actually even have an informal proof, I hope that someone can comment on it:

Consider an outcome $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $\tau(\omega)<\infty$. Set $t:=\tau(\omega)$, then we know that $\omega\in A$ if and only if $\omega\in A\cap\{\tau\leq t\}$. Since $A\cap\{\tau\leq t\}$ is in $F_t$ (recall that $A\in F_\tau$), we know whether $\omega\in A\cap\{\tau\leq t\}$ and hence we know whether $\omega\in A$. Hence $A\in F_t=F_{\tau(\omega)}$. I feel like I have cheated.

Comment: Suppose $\tau$ is  a **finite** stopping time  which takes all values in $(0,\infty)$ and $A \in F_{\tau}$. You are saying that $A \in F_s$ for every $s$. There are easy counter-examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me quite some time to figure out where the argument went wrong. As @geetha290krm pointed out in the comment, it is easy to find counter-examples. But, I will try to give some intuition why it should actually not hold.

Saying that $A\in\mathcal{F}_\tau$ means that $A\cap\{\tau \leq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$ for any $t$. This can be interpreted by saying that knowing $\{\tau\leq t\}$ and having the knowledge up to time $t$, we can decide whether $A$ happens or not. On the other hand, $A\in \mathcal{F}_t$ means that, with the knowledge up to time $t$ (and nothing additional), we can decide whether $A$ happens or not.

In your argument sou chose some $\omega$ and some $t$ such that $\tau(\omega) = t$. Then, you said that $\omega\in A$ iff $\omega \in A\cap\{\tau \leq t\}$ which is absolutely correct. However, and that is the important points, *you do not cover the whole set $A$*! More precisely, there might be some $\omega\in A$ such that $\tau(\omega) > t$. For those, your argument doesn't work and that is why the argument breaks down.

Comment: "However, and that is the important points, you do not cover the whole set A!" - Even that wouldn't suffice, would it? $A\in F_t$ means that I know $A$ at time $t$ **for all outcomes**, so I have to cover the whole set $\Omega$, don't I?

Comment: Yes. I did not formulate it well. In some sense, you only considered $A\cap \{\tau\leq t\}$ which is in $\mathcal{F}_t$ by definition, but you do not consider $A\cap \{\tau > t\}$. I hope that helps.

Comment: Suppose $0\leq t$ and $A\in F_\tau$. I showed that we know $A$ at time $t$ for all outcomes in $\{\tau\leq t\}$. Of course this is precisely what we expect given that $F_\tau$ is supposed to be the information up to time $\tau$. My mistake was to conclude that $A\in F_t$, since this actually requires that we know $A$ at time $t$ **for all outcomes**. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the correct view :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $0\leq t$ and $A\in F_\tau$. I showed that we know $A$ at time $t$ for all outcomes in $\{\tau\leq t\}$. Of course this is precisely what we expect given that $F_\tau$ is supposed to be the information up to time $\tau$. My mistake was to conclude that $A\in F_t$, since this actually requires that we know $A$ at time $t$ **for all outcomes**. In fact if $\{\tau\leq t\}=\Omega$ then $A=A\cap\{\tau\leq t\}\in F_t$.